# How could I make a constant in C except using a number

Tags: c, macros

I am working on a C math library, and it is using macros do to the most of it's work, I am now facing a problem.

This is what the macro looks like:

```
the_macro(a, b, c)
```

and the macro itself does something like:
`(a - b > 0) ? error_function : 1`

the error_function is used to stop the user at complie time, so if `(a - b > 0)` is `true`, then the macro will expand as a function which does not have a definition. So this will cause a linkage error.

Everthing seems good, but today my boss told me we need to do some unit-test, so I wrote a function which wraps the macro:

```
int my_func(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return the_macro(a, b, c);
}
```

here comes the problem, the code can't pass linkage, because if I use a var instead of a constant to call the_macro, these `error_functions` will be in the `.o` file, because the `int a, int b, int c` are all known at runtime, so I can only call the macro function with constants: `the_macro(2, 3, 4)` is there any way to avoid this? or is there a better solution to do unit-test on this macro?

**EDIT:**

The code I'm working on is confidential... but I made an example which demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define the_macro(a, b)\
    (a > b)?error_function():1

// Comment out my_func(), then the program will run normaly
// But if you don't comment it out, the linkage error will come out.
void my_func(int a, int b)
{
    the_macro(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", the_macro(1, 10));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using gcc-4

Comment: A macro is replaced by its definition before compilation even starts, so calling with constants or not shouldn't make a difference. There is likely to be some other problem: what's the exact error message?

Comment: @dbaupp it will say `error_function` has no definition

Comment: @dbaupp but if I call the macro with constants, everything is good

Comment: Is `error_function` defined before the definition of `my_func`? (do you `#include` the appropriate file?)

Comment: (Also, unless you have a specific reason for it, `a > b` is a better way of expressing `a - b > 0`.)

Comment: @dbaupp I did include the appropriate files:) it seems that if I pass a constant in to the macro, the `error_function` won't be generated to the `.o` file(the symbol table), but if I use a var, it will be generated to the symbol table anyway.

Comment: @dbaupp: `a - b > 0` is the best way of expressing `a - b > 0`. It is a poor way of expressing `a > b`, though.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, what's the difference in functionality? (Ignoring differences with wrap-around, which fall under "having a specific reason".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of where you use the macro, if `error_function` is not declared, you should get a compiler error.  If it is declared but not defined, you have undefined behavior.  Whether the arguments to the macro are constants or not changes nothing in this respect.  (It may affect what the actual behavior is in the case of undefined behavior.)

Comment: there are tones of `error_functions` in the code, I don't want to write a definition for each of them...

Comment: @shengy It's that or undefined behavior.

Comment: I spent my whole afternoon:) and things are working now, thanks, though and everyone is all correct, thank you for helping me solve this problem. Sometimes I got very confused about why they write code like this....

Answer (score 2):

When you call the macro with constants, the compiler knows the value and thus, perhaps as as optimization, the expression `the_macro (5, 4, 0)` gets replaced by `1` instead of `error_function`. When your expression `a-b` evaluates to `<= 0`, your compiler replaces it with `error_function`, and stops your compilation.

On the other hand, when you use variables, the compiler doesn't know the result of the expression and has to use the full expansion of the macro, which contains a call to undefined function, and hence you get the linkage error.

Comment: so this means I can only call this macro with constants?

Comment: The compiler may or may not do the replacement. A compiler which does not do the replacement is fully standard compliant, so any code which uses this macro is violating the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of your unit tests (only) why not define `error_function()` as part of your unit test and have it return an error unconditionally that your test framework can detect. That way you should be able to mimic the behaviour you're seeing at compile time using either constants or variables.

It's not *exactly* what you want, but unit test frameworks are always, by their nature run-time testing mechanisms, so an automated compile time test is probably not going to be possible.

Alternatively, you could use `system()` to run a command line build including your library, redirect the output, including errors into a file. You could then open the file and scan for known text of the linkage error.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understand this correctly:

You want a way to break compilation if `a-b>0`? This is actually impossible unless you use C11. There simply is no way to have the compiler abort depending on a condition. In your case you are trying to use a combination of the optimizer and the linker to get the desired behavior. But this cannot work reliably.

The expression `(a - b > 0) ? error_function : 1` **may** be reduced by the optimizer to one if a-b>0, but this is not guaranteed. There is a guaranteed behavior compiler has to show defined by the C standard and this standard does not mention an optimizer. The same optimizer may sometimes reduce the expression, and sometimes not reduce it depending on other things in your code. Or it may or may not reduce it depending on the command line flags you are passing.

So with using this macro you are writing code, which may suddenly break unexpectedly when you switch compiler, compiler version, operating system, add or remove linked libraries or target architecture. Code that suddenly breaks depending on such changes is very bad. Don't do this to your fellow developers.

Better to write portable code for which you can be sure that future compilers will understand it because it follows the standard. In pre C11 there is no way to do this. If you  really need this, tell your boss the only way is to use C11 which has a `static_assert` keyword which can give you the conditional abortion of the compilation.